# Conclusion of 'The Trial for Murder' by Charles Dickens

Tags: meaning, short-stories, charles-dickens

What does the last quote of the short story '[The Trial for Murder](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1289/1289-h/1289-h.htm#page303)' mean? Why did the 'Murderer' says

> [...] Before I was taken, he somehow got to my bedside in the night, woke me, 
>   and put a rope round my neck."

Was the speaker kinda hypnotized and killed the 'Murderer' even before the hearing? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what we are to understand is that, just as the narrator has seen the murderer and the murdered man in incorporeal form, and remember that when he saw them from his window:

> Both men threaded their way among the other passengers with a smoothness hardly consistent even with the action of walking on a pavement; and no single creature, that I could see, gave them place, touched them, or looked after them.

In the same way, the murderer has seen a phantasmagorical version of the narrator, at his bedside hanging the noose about his neck.